# how to setting limit size of file when creating AWS S3 presigned url via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i want to create S3 presigned url and given to the client with spesific limit file size, in example min file size in 200kib and max file size is 1024 kib

I create using function `create_presigned_url`

```py
create_presigned_url = await s3_client.create_presigned_url(
        client_method="put_object",
        method_parameters={
            "Bucket": settings.S3_Bucket,
            "Key": f"application/registration/{find_application_id.get('application_id')}/{req_upload_document.document_type}/{first_char}{time_reformat}.jpg",
            "ContentLengthRange": [200, 1024],
        },
    )
```

and i found error, because parameter is invalid for content length range.

```sh
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "ContentLengthRange", must be one of: ACL, Body, Bucket, CacheControl, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentLength, ContentMD5, ContentType, Expires, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWriteACP, Key, Metadata, ServerSideEncryption, StorageClass, WebsiteRedirectLocation, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, SSEKMSKeyId, SSEKMSEncryptionContext, BucketKeyEnabled, RequestPayer, Tagging, ObjectLockMode, ObjectLockRetainUntilDate, ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus, ExpectedBucketOwner
```

where i can put the content length range in this functions ? Thanks in advance